# Cucumber Exception: Couldn't load plugin class: com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.ScenarioReporter

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, reportportal

I was trying to upgrade cucumber to use parallel execution feature, ended up issues with report portal.

In compatibility matrix it says:

Version(s) of cucumber java and cucumber junit - 4.0.0 - 4.2.6 Tested version of cucumber agent 4.0.0

I tried to different version of cucumber 4.0.0, 4.2.3, 4.2.2, 4.2.6 with cucumber agent 4.0.0
It says

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class:
>   com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.ScenarioReporter. It does not implement
>   cucumber.api.Plugin

```
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:176)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:163)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:220)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(PluginFactory.java:203)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:385)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:164)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:107)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:100)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:96)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:23)
at com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber.<init>(ExtendedCucumber.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

POM has following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--ReportPortal-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>agent-java-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: cucumber 4 reporting is event based and is different than previous versions. so this error makes some sense.  Make sure you have cucumber core & cucumber-junit with version >4 and it should be same versions.

Comment: @Sureshmani Why why need cucumber core? Any how I tried to add that dependency still I see same issue.

Answer (score 2):

From cucumber 4 and above, the custom plugin needs to implement one of cucumber.api.event.EventListener or cucumber.api.event.ConcurrentEventListener interface. Else one can also implement the cucumber.api.StepDefinitionReporter and/or cucumber.api.SummaryPrinter. These in turn extend the cucumber.api.Plugin interface.

The plugin you are using implements gherkin.formatter.Formatter and gherkin.formatter.Reporter interface

There is already an issue for this - https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber/issues/10 and also solution given in the same - https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber/issues/10#issuecomment-438434717.

Also a compatibility table for different cucumber versions is mentioned in the github page - https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber#compatibility-matrix-for-cucumber-agents

Comment: actually its got resolved after I used agent-java-cucumber3 instead of agent-java-cucumber4